Broken install (r-base-core)
I've been trying to install r-base-core on my Ubuntu 24.04 machine, and getting the following dependency errors:
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.8 is to be installed
               Depends: libcurl4t64 (>= 7.28.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libglib2.0-0t64 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libicu74 (>= 74.1-1~) but it is not installable
               Depends: libpng16-16t64 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not installable
               Depends: libreadline8t64 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libtiff6 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
               Depends: libtirpc3t64 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installable
               Depends: libxt6t64 but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed

Despite multiple attempts to fix the problem (--fix-broken install, update, upgrade), these are not getting fixed. Thanks in advance for any help on this.

You state you're using 24.04 or noble, but your pasted details seem to match a 22.04 or jammy system, ie. libc6 | 2.35-0ubuntu3.8  | jammy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x is the libc6 package your system reports as installed...  I suggest checking what release you're using as your description doesn't match pasted detail.  FYI:  If you were using 24.04 as stated; you'd be getting libc6 | 2.39-0ubuntu8.3  | noble-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x which meets the rule in the paste

Actually, you are right. I have two machines, both identical in hardware (Lenovo Yoga), and I had upgraded one to 24.04 earlier. The one where I'm having difficulty with R is the 22.04 version.

apt-cache policy r-base-core please add this to your question through [edit] and also sudo apt update
